# Using jQuery to 'click' a li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, document-ready

I have a `<ul>` element that dynamically generates the `<li>` elements and simply want to run a `onclick` event

```html
<ul id="results">
    <li class="device_result searchterm" data-url="apple-iphone-5s">
        <a href="#"> Apple iPhone 5s </a>
    </li>
    <li class="device_result searchterm" data-url="apple-iphone-5c">
        <a href="#"> Apple iPhone 5s </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've got the following jQuery in a `$(document).ready` block but it doesn't seem to work - any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```js
$("li .searchterm").click(function() {  
    console.log("testing");
});
```

Comment: class name should be added along with element. `li.searchterm`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

if you add dinamically put the click on the list but select the items:

```
$("#results").on("click", ".searchterm", function(event){
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

try on the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/emPKS/

Answer (score 14):

Remove the space in selector

```
  $("li.searchterm").click(function() {    
   console.log('testing');
});
```

and You can also use `.on` to attach the specific event to the matched elements

```
  $("li.searchterm").on("click",function() {    
   console.log('testing');
});
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B9VAA/)

Comment: omg.. did i just make that EPIC fail then lol :-) thanks Sachin - much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As your content is added dynamically so it is not accessible directly ,So you have to use Event delegation.

```
$('#results').on('click','li.searchterm',function() {    
    console.log('testing');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Either do

```
$( "li .searchterm" ).on('click', function() {    
   console.log('testing');
});
```

OR

```
<li class="device_result searchterm" data-url="apple-iphone-5s" onclick="clickFunc(1)">
   <a href="#">Apple iPhone 5s</a>
</li>
<li class="device_result searchterm" data-url="apple-iphone-5c" onclick="clickFunc(2)">
   <a href="#">Apple iPhone 5s</a>
</li>
```

And the Javascrip

```
function clickFunc(id) {
   console.log('Do something with ' + id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without assigning id to ul

```
$('ul').on('click','li.searchterm',function(){
//do your stuffhere;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "li.searchterm" ).on('click',function() {    
   console.log('testing');
});
```