# Show li on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have

```html
    <nav>
        <ul class="sel">
              <li>
                  <a href="#LINK1" data-title="A">A</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#LINK2"  data-title="B">B</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#LINK3" data-title="C">C</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

When the page loads I would like the `<li>` with `<a href='#LINK1' data-title="A">A</a>` to be selected and showing. I have tried multiple jQuery solutions and none have worked.

Is it possible to have this `<li>` containing this specific `<a>` show when the page loads?

I have many solutions such as:

[Using jQuery to 'click' a li element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091299/using-jquery-to-click-a-li-element)

[Click trigger on page load (UL > LI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130984/click-trigger-on-page-load-ul-li)

Comment: What have jQuery solution have you tried?

Comment: You could do this with plain CSS

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid; the `href` attribute defines a target url for the `<a>` element to navigate to, but you were using it to define your id. Instead, the id should be applied to the `<li>` element you are trying to hide/show. Take a look at the example below, which hides the first `<li>` element if the other elements are clicked:

```js
var display = function(pageHide,pageShow) {
  var current = "#DATA" + pageShow.toString();
  $(current).show();
  var last = "#DATA" + pageHide.toString();
  $(last).hide();
}; // hide/show pages.

$(document).ready(function() {
  var page = 1;         // set default page
  $('#DATA2').hide();   // hide others
  $('#DATA3').hide();
  $('#LINK1').click(function() {
    display(page,1);
    page = 1;
  });
  $('#LINK2').click(function() {
    display(page,2);
    page = 2;
  });
  $('#LINK3').click(function() {
    display(page,3);
    page = 3;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="sel">
    <li id="LINK1">
      <a data-title="A" href="#">A</a>
    </li>
    <li id="LINK2">
      <a data-title="B" href="#">B</a>
    </li>
    <li id="LINK3">
      <a data-title="C" href="#">C</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p id="DATA1">main</p>
  <p id="DATA2">graphs</p>
  <p id="DATA3">notes</p>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is not working for me. The <li> contains an <a> that links to a div that is displayed. I am trying to have this already displayed when the page loads and go away when another <a> in an <li> is clicked. I couldn't figure out how to implement this with css only

Comment: @MikeElJackson Please take a look at the edited answer. Does this answer your question?

Comment: so A, B, and C are tabs on a dashboard. A corresponds to a main page, B corresponds to graphs, and C corresponds to a notes section. When the web page is loaded I want A, the main page, to show. But when I click the tab for B or C I want it to switch to the respective graphs or notes section. However, when I click the A tab again I want the main page to show. I have the tabs switching between each other but I can't get the A tab to show when the page loads. The code you have above removes A completely when BorC is selected, but I am trying to select A and then switch to B,C and then back to A

Comment: right now when I load the webpage neither A nor B nor C show

Comment: @MikeElJackson Ok, I get a basic sense of what you are trying to accomplish... take a look at the new code snippet. There is only one disadvantage to using this method, which is that if you press a link twice it will hide the current page, but it's a start. Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use Pseudo selector using data-title and do whatever you want. I would also like to do something like:

> $('ul li').filter(function(index){});

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul li a[data-title=A]').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#0000ff');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="sel">
    <li>
      <a href="#LINK1" data-title="A">A</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#LINK2" data-title="B">B</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#LINK3" data-title="C">C</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: hmm this did not work for me I tried .css('display','block')

Comment: All those are already visible, why you would set display property to block?
Can you put your code in fiddler and show me?